# How to run a cell in ipython notebook as if it where a script?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Typical use of the magic command `%run` is

```
%run foo.py
```

for some script file `foo.py`.

Is there a way to use this command to run a cell, e.g. `In[83]`, instead of `foo.py`?

---

This can be done simply by executing:

`exec(In[83])`

Comment: What do you mean by "run a cell"? You want the content of each cell to be a string that you want to execute as Python code?

Comment: @JackManey in IPython:notebook you can have "pages" of code and results of executed code, each page is called cell.

Comment: Yes, I mean that exactly, @JackManey Maybe a good idea will be to write the content of the cell to an auxiliary file but, is there a less "baroque" way to do this?

Comment: @Santiago This smells of a very, very bad code design. What led to your need to do this?

Comment: @JackManey I agree with you, but I was thinking that it would be a good idea to execute code inside a given cell with the ´%run´ command to use, for instance, the -d -n (debug) options.

Comment: Again, I'm struggling to imagine a scenario in which that would be a good idea. If nothing else, however, there's `eval`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: @JackManey I think `eval` is just what I was looking for, thank you a lot (you might have noticed that I am new to python, though). With regards to the scenario, I understand your feeling (you surely are one of those who code elegantly), but in my case I was just trying some pieces of code for some quick simulations and It would be useful _e.g._ to run some written cell in a loop changing some parameter... I know it may not be good practice, but it might prove useful I think.

Comment: @JackManey I have tried `eval()` but it did not work out due to the fact that it evaluates but it does not make assignments, for instance. The answer to my question is the function `exec()`.

Comment: I agree this could lead to some bad code design but I find running `exec(In[1])` in the middle of a large notebook helpful to redo all the `import` statements when I am starting from unpickled data, i.e., the first half of my notebook does some data manipulation/collection and the second half does some analysis/plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Santiago, you can do that simply calling your foo.py each time you need. This is the samr that "call a cell" by their "name" (i.e. In[83] or whatever). That are the advantages of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`%load 83` then Enter will be shorter to write than `exec(In[83])` and will work all the time (almost same context).

Furthermore, it allows you to modify the cell (which is often useful)